# SpannableString html annotation

Tags: android, spannablestring

I followed a tutorial in here [Styling internationalized text in Android](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f)
and used code:

```kotlin
SpannedString titleText = (SpannedString) getText(R.string.title);
Annotation[] annotations = titleText.getSpans(0, titleText.length(), Annotation.class);
SpannableString spannableString1 = new SpannableString(titleText);
  for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
    if (annotation.getKey().equals("id")) {
      final String fontName = annotation.getValue();
      spannableString1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
      titleText.getSpanStart(annotation),
      titleText.getSpanEnd(annotation),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      spannableString1.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fontName + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }, titleText.getSpanStart(annotation), titleText.getSpanEnd(annotation), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
  }
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(spannableString1);
```

I tested this with string `<string name="title"><i>Best practices for</i> <annotation id="1">text1</annotation> on Android <annotation id="2">text2</annotation></string>` in `string.xml` and it run so good.
But I want move string from `string.xml` to `MainActivity.class` with code

```kotlin
String title="<i>Best practices for</i> <annotation id=\"1\">text1</annotation> on Android <annotation id=\"2\">text2</annotation>";
SpannedString titleText = new SpannedString(title);//
Annotation[] annotations = titleText.getSpans(0, titleText.length(), Annotation.class);
...
```

but it not working. It shows all tag of html in my TextView.
How can I change text from `string.xml` to `MainActivity.java` and have same result?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()` :

```
SpannedString titleText = new SpannedString(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(title, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Comment: Thank you. your code will remove tag in TextView but my SpannableString  not show.